# Pseudo TTY in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstask, io-redirection, pty

Currently I am working on developing a GUI to some command line tools for Jailbroken iOS devices.  I am using NSTask and verified that I was able to capture both stdout and stderr error and print the output to a UITextField.  How ever most of the commands that I wish to run are not outputting anything.  I suspect that setting up a pseudo tty session would fix this but am unable to find how to set this up in obj-c.  My question is

1) Does this sound reasonable that the commands (namely arp-scan and nmap) need a TTY session?
2) How would I go about setting up a fake TTY session in Obj-c?

Comment: I'm guessing the hard part is implementing the paper tape punch.